# Pine script draw horizontal line for open price at a certain local time

Tags: pine-script

[Pine script] I would like to draw the horizontal line for open price, every day at a certain local time (e.g. 07:00 GMT+8), the open price for the 1st trading day of month.

May I know how to write the pinescript?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

There are built-in functions like `dayofmonth`, `hour`, `minute` and more. You can use those to figure out if the current bar is at a specific time or date.

Then you can draw your line based on that check.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

_d = 1  // Day 1
_h = 7  // Hour: 7
_m = 0  // Minute: 0
inWindow = (dayofmonth(time) == _d) and (hour(time) == _h) and (minute(time) == _m)

var line l = na

if (inWindow)
    l := line.new(bar_index, open, bar_index + 1, open, extend=extend.right, color=color.orange, width=2)
    line.delete(l[1])
```

[image]